# App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have seen many answers that say we must add procfile and requirements.txt and manage.py in same directory, I have all these files including .git in same folder (directory)

here is my procfile and requirements.txt, you can see my file structure as well on left
[procfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4USYq.png)

[requirements.txt snap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TZSU.png)
[requirements.txt snap 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Y4g.png)
my branch is main so I am using git push heroku main:
[git status showing branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io9tf.png)
but still I receive this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aPO2.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: But note that `procfile` ≠ `Procfile` and `requirments.txt` ≠ `requirements.txt`.